# TableView created in storyboard is drawn starting from the topmost edge of the screen where it overlaps with the status bar

Tags: uitableview, statusbar, ios7

I added a TableViewController in the storyboard using XCode 5 and added tableviewcells. However when I run it in simulator, the tableview is drawn starting from the topmost edge of the screen overlapping the status bar. The status bar should come first,  then the tableview below it.

Is there any settings I missed?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you read the Apple iOS 7 transitioning guide ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html)): *Updating the UI > Bars and Buttons* which discusses the new translucent status bar and how to change it.

Quote from the beta documentation:

> In iOS 7, you can control the style of the status bar from an individual view controller and change it while the app runs. If you prefer to opt out of this behavior and set the status bar style by using the UIApplicationstatusBarStyle method, add the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key to an app’s Info.plist file and give it the value NO.